# How can I retain break lines programmatically copied to the clipboard using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

Using Javascript and a couple of devexpress asp.net controls to programmatically copy the contents of a ASPxMemo (multiline textfield) and set the contents as the body of an email.

The copy and paste works for the most part but I notice that if, in my ASPxMemo, i have multiple lines, it gets pasted into the body of the email as one line.  For example, if this was in the ASPxMemo:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

I'd like to retain the original format but as of now the email's body would be pasted as:

```
aaabbbccc
```

The action occurs on the click of an ASPxButton:

```
<dx:ASPxButton id="btnClipboardCopy" runat="server">
    <Image Url="clipboard.png"></Image>
    <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) { 
            let subject = 'Submission';
            let body = footnote.GetText();
            window.open('mailto:helpdesk@xxx.com?subject=' + subject + '&' + 'body=' + body);
        }"
    />
</dx:ASPxButton>
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your Email compose window opens up in HTML mode, so you need to replace newline characters in the body with `<br>`. Try adding the following line to your JS click handler after you initialed the body var:

```
body = body.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
```

Note, if this doesn't work out of the box you may need to play with escaping `<` and `>` because you're actually constructing a link. So, additional fix to try:

```
body = body.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '%3Cbr%3E');
```

HTH